# Remote Server Sync with Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a table with over 85000 rows of mysql queries, and would like to run this queries into a remote server.

Example:

```
------------------------------------------------------------
|id  | queries   | querydate   | status |datecreated
|1   | INSERT    | 2018-02-12  | 0      |2018-02-12 10:10:10 
     | into....  |
```

Above is my query table example, now I would like to run all this queries 85000 in number into a remote server, doing a foreach with php takes forever is there a better way
[Table Sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MENaO.jpg).

Comment: what did you so far?

Comment: I simple pulled record from the local db and looped through each entry and make it run on a remote server with a different db connection, this happens to be very slow and am looking at merging the queries but that isn't going well enough

Answer (score 0):

Bulk the queries together and make use of PHP Data Objects.

```
  $this->legacy_db = $this->load->database('online_db', TRUE); 

  $dbhost = $this->legacy_db->hostname;
  $dbuser = $this->legacy_db->username;
  $dbpass = $this->legacy_db->password;
  $dbname = $this->legacy_db->database;


  // Create connection
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$dbhost;dbname=$dbname", $dbuser, $dbpass);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

  $conn->query($sql);
```